# For Loops in Base R - How do the double brackets function (and lead to the boost in processing speed)?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop

I have been trying to construct a base R `For`loop I could speed test alongside other R package functions.

Unfortunately, I seem to have a gap in my understanding of 1) how for loops must be constructed, 2) how small syntactical differences lead to significant changes in processing speeds, and 3) if those first two matters are somehow related. My education never touched upon these subjects. All the resources I can find don't explain the empirical results.

For example, let's take a seeded random dataframe that is populated with values between 1 and 5. All values greater than 4 are to be replaced with zeros. I use four permutations of `for` loops with differing bracketing structures in order to find all the values that are greater than 4 and replace them with zeros.
Three of these are fully functioning for loops, and there is an interesting relationship exhibited between how many double brackets are used, and the increases in speed that result.

This is not about silent integer coercion as far as I can tell. 
The speed differences seen between bracket counts are fully independent of if they start out as integers or doubles, or get tested as integers or doubles, or get replaced as integers or doubles, as well as all combinations of the above. I have tested all these and find that all those variations contribute significantly less to the final speed than the bracketing does.

***Why is the number of brackets used causing these variations in speed?*** 
Also, a probably much simpler question: ***Why the does version with the double bracket in the 'testing/filtering' vector not function?*** - even though leaving it out entirely, or adding another double bracket in front causes it to work.

Please find my example code below:

```
set.seed(24)
# Numeric Dataframe
df_numeric_orig <- as.data.frame(matrix(sample(c(1:5), 1e6 *12, replace=TRUE),
                              dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("var", 1:12)), ncol=12))

## No Double Brackets
df_num <- df_numeric_orig
NumDF_NoSetsDbleBrackets <- 
system.time({
    for(row in 1:ncol(df_num)) {
        df_num[row][(df_num[row] > 4)] <- 0
    }
})

# 1 set Double Brackets - Front
df_num <- df_numeric_orig
NumDF_1SetDbleBrackets_front <- 
system.time({
    for(row in 1:ncol(df_num)) {
        df_num[[row]][(df_num[row] > 4)] <- 0
    }
})

# 1 set Double Brackets - Back
df_num <- df_numeric_orig
NumDF_1SetDbleBrackets_back <- 
system.time({
    for(row in 1:ncol(df_num)) {
        df_num[row][(df_num[[row]] > 4)] <- 0
    }
})

# 2 set Double Brackets 
df_num <- df_numeric_orig
NumDF_2SetDbleBrackets <- 
    system.time({
        for(row in 1:ncol(df_num)) {
            df_num[[row]][(df_num[[row]] > 4)] <- 0
        }
    })


NumDF_NoSetsDbleBrackets
NumDF_1SetDbleBrackets_front
NumDF_1SetDbleBrackets_back
NumDF_2SetDbleBrackets
```

I know that I can wrap these loops in local functions, and thus not have to replace the dataframe each time; however, I want to remove as many obstacles as possible for reviewers to allow reviewers to be able to observe directly that these for loops do in fact function effectively. i.e.: syntactic convention does not sufficient explanation make.

```
The speed results on my machine typically come out about as below:
> NumDF_NoSetsDbleBrackets
   user  system elapsed 
   0.41    0.13    0.55 
> NumDF_1SetDbleBrackets_front
   user  system elapsed 
   0.25    0.10    0.35 
> NumDF_1SetDbleBrackets_back
Error: object 'NumDF_1SetDbleBrackets_back' not found
> NumDF_2SetDbleBrackets
   user  system elapsed 
   0.23    0.05    0.29
```

Comment: try using `class` on each object after indexing it. `class(mtcars[1])` versus `class(mtcars[[1]])`

Comment: Maybe read this to learn the difference: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html

Comment: I agre with Zelazny7 about the overhead inherent in data frames as opposed to atomic vectors. Also, the one that doesn't run at all is because `df_num[row]` returns a single column data frame. Indexing it again the same way, with single brackets, seeks to select another collection of columns. But you only have one column, whereas you seem to think that `[df_num[[row]] > 4]` is acting on the remaining column as a vector.

Comment: @MrFlick - Aha! It looks like subsetting is the word for which I should have been searching. Reading up now.